# Puppet certificate store

Tags: ruby, ssl-certificate, puppet

i got a Puppet Enterprise Master Server 2018.1.3 which should get the Code with Code Manager from a git-Repository via https, where the server certificate of the git server is signed by a third party CA.

after getting everything afaik correctly configured, i get following:

```
>  puppet-code deploy --dry-run
Dry-run deploying all environments.
Errors while collecting a list of environments to deploy (exit code: 1).
ERROR    -> Unable to determine current branches for Git source 'puppet' 
(/etc/puppetlabs/code-staging/environments)
Original exception:
The SSL certificate is invalid
```

executing directly `r10k` produces a similar error. which makes sense, since i have not installed the third party CA certificate anywhere yet.

so i thought, `r10k` most likely runs jruby which runs java (i do not any idea about ruby), so i will install the certificate in the jvm:

```
keytool -import -file gitCA.cer -alias gitCA -keystore /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/java/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

but i am still getting the same error, also after a system restart, so ok, it means `r10k` does not use jruby but ruby, so i will install also the certificate in the OS, put the certificate under `/etc/pki/trust/anchors` and called `update-ca-certificates` (on SLES12). After that, i can access the git-Repo-URL with `wget` without getting any certificate error, so the certificate is installed in the OS correctly, but still, even after a system restart, i am getting the same error with `r10k`.

after lot of goggling for certificate stores and ruby i found out that

```
export  SSL_CERT_FILE=<path_to_cert>
```

fixes the direct call of `r10k`:

```
> r10k deploy display --fetch                                         ---
:sources:
- :name: :puppet
 :basedir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments"
 :remote: https://xxx@git.xxx/git/puppet
 :environments:
  - develop
  - master
  - production
  - puppet_test
```

but `puppet-code` still not working with same error message. but i thought, obviously i am right now `root` and `puppet-code` is executed by user `pe-puppet`, so i put the export command in the `/etc/profile.local` file, so it is available to all users.

still not working. even after system restart and deleting `/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/r10k/` that was created with user `root` while directly calling `r10k`.

first question: why does `r10k` works, but `puppet-code` not?

second question: where is the correct place for that certificate?

many thanks
Michael

### UPDATE: 27.AUG.2018

i tried this:

```
sudo -H -u pe-puppet bash -c '/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/r10k deploy display --fetch'
```

which did not work, despite i am setting the `SSL_CERT_FILE` variable in the `/etc/profile.local` file.

but i got it working by setting the variable in the `/etc/environment` file.

but `puppet code` still not working. why?

Comment: I think if you use `ssh` credentials instead that would fix all of this. Typically people use those in conjunction with a service account.

Comment: @matt: thanks, but I have to access git over https, i do not have any choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those looking for a solution to this problem checkout this post on the [Puppet Support Base](https://support.puppet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005418487-Use-Code-Manager-to-deploy-code-from-a-repository-with-a-self-signed-certificate-for-Puppet-Enterprise-2016-1-to-2016-4-2017-1-2017-3-and-2018-1-7).

Simply put you have two options:

1. Use a Git source instead of an HTTPS source to refer to your repository in your Puppetfile. This option requires adding SSH keys to your Puppet master and your repository.
2. Add a certificate authority (CA) cert for the repository to the list of trusted CAs in /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/cert.pem.

Option one: Use a Git source instead of an HTTPS source

To deploy code from your repository using a Git source, configure a private SSH key on your Puppet master and a public SSH key on your repository:

In your Puppetfile, change references to your Git repository from an HTTPS source to a Git source:

For example, change:

`mod 'site_date', :git: 'https://example.com/user/site_data.git',`

to:

`mod 'site_data', :git: 'ssh://user@example.com:22/user/site_data.git',`

Configure your SSH keys. Configure the private key using our documentation on how to Declare module or data content with SSH private key authentication for PE 2018.1.

Note: Use the version selector to choose the right version of our documentation for your deployment.

The details of configuring your public key depend on how your Git repository is configured. Talk to your Git repository administrator.

Option two: Add a trusted CA cert
If you are unable to specify a Git s
ource, add your repository to the list of CAs trusted by Code Manager by adding a CA cert to the file `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/cert.pem.`

Transfer the cert (ca.pem) file to your CA node.

On the CA node, add the cert to the list of CAs trusted by Code Manager: `cat ca.pem >> /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/cert.pem`

Agent runs won't revert changes made to cert.pem because the file isn't managed by PE, but upgrades to PE will overwrite the file. After you upgrade PE, you must add the CA cert to cert.pem again.

Comment: many thanks, Option1 was no go in this situation, and Option2 is indeed the best way, i did not know about the file /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/cert.pem, many thanks.. but i am wonder why puppet is not using the OS certificate store, but so be it.

Answer (score 0):

so, i got it working, but not happy with the solution.

i turned on debug logging on `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/logback.xml`, confirming that `puppet-code` is indeed calling `r10k`:

```
2018-08-27T14:54:24.149+02:00 DEBUG [qtp462609859-78] [p.c.core] Invoking shell: 
  /opt/puppetlabs/bin/r10k deploy --config /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/code-manager/r10k.yaml --verbose warn display --format=json --fetch
2018-08-27T14:54:24.913+02:00 ERROR [qtp462609859-78] [p.c.app] Errors while collecting a list of environments to deploy (exit code: 1). 
  ERROR   -> Unable to determine current branches for Git source 'puppet' (/etc/puppetlabs/code-staging/environments)
  Original exception:
  The SSL certificate is invalid
```

so i did it the very quick and dirty way:

```
cd /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/
mv r10k r10k-bin
touch r10k
chmod +x r10k
vi r10k
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
export SSL_CERT_FILE=<new_cert_path>
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/r10k-bin "$@"
```

now it is working:

```
puppet:~ # puppet-code deploy --dry-run
Dry-run deploying all environments.
Found 5 environments.
```

but not happy, any better idea?